# Org mode: Simple "if" formula on my table throws an error

Tags: org-mode, org-table, spreadsheet, formula

I have a very simple table that looks like this:

```
| Fabricant | Catégorie | Animal                 | Nombre |
|-----------+-----------+------------------------+--------|
| Pearson   | Camp      | Bœuf                   |      1 |
| Pearson   |           | Castor                 |      1 |
| Pearson   |           | Chèvre                 |      2 |
| Pearson   |           | Cougar                 |      2 |
```

On which I apply this `if` formula as I have seen on the [org mode documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html):

```
#+TBLFM: $5 = if($4 < 2, test, string(''))
```

But it throws an error:

```
| Fabricant | Catégorie | Animal                 | Nombre |        |
|-----------+-----------+------------------------+--------+--------|
| Pearson   | Camp      | Bœuf                   |      1 | #ERROR |
| Pearson   |           | Castor                 |      1 | #ERROR |
| Pearson   |           | Chèvre                 |      2 | #ERROR |
| Pearson   |           | Cougar                 |      2 | #ERROR |
```

I'm very new to Org mode, Emacs and spreadsheet formulas in general so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know well the formula syntax for `calc`, but it seems that if you follow exactly the syntax of string constant that the documentation uses, it will work. Namely, replace `''` by `""`:

```lisp
#+TBLFM: $5 = if($4 < 2, test, string(""))
```

Can't explain why, though. There is also [a formula syntax for Emacs Lisp](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp) that you might find more intuitive.

In your case, it translates to:

```lisp
#+TBLFM: $5 = '(if (< (string-to-number $4) 2) "test" "")
```

which can be made shorter, as @gigiair pointed out, using `N` mode switch (all referenced elements will be numbers):

```lisp
#+TBLFM: $5 = '(if (< $4 2) "test" ""); N
```

You might also find useful to toggle the formula debugger `org-table-toggle-formula-debugger` (`C-c {`) which would show you the expansion of the formula and an error message if applicable.

Comment: You can avoid the string-to-number function with the tag N : $5='(if (< $4  2)  "test"  "");N

Comment: I suspect that `calc` takes its string definition from `elisp`, hence the double quotes. See the "Strings" section of the Calc manual: `C-h i g (Calc) Strings`.